# combining functionality of csv to Excel and deleting row where #N/A

Tags: vbscript

I want to combine the functionalities of two codes. My first code is converting a csv file to an excel file and saving it with a different name. 
I want to add a functionality of deleting the entire row in a file  where column A is #N/A. There may be a small thing to fix it but I am not able to work
it out because I am not good at it.

```
file = "C:\PR\TEST\Sizetest.csv"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

txt = fso.OpenTextFile(file).ReadAll

fso.OpenTextFile(file, 2).Write Replace(Replace(txt, "¬", vbTab), Chr(34), "")

'Set obj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 'Calls the File System Object  

Const xlDelimited = 1
Const xlNormal = -4143 

Dim Excel
Set Excel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
With Excel
    .Workbooks.Open "C:\PR\TEST\Sizetest.csv"
    .Sheets(1).Columns("A").TextToColumns .Range("A1"), xlDelimited, , , , True  'semicolon-delimited

    .ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs .ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Size_test1", xlNormal
    .Quit

'    fso.DeleteFile("C:\PR\TEST\Sizetest.csv") 'Deletes the file throught the DeleteFile function 
End With
```

This is the second code. This should delete entire row whereever there is  #N/A in column A. I want the record to be deleted either before the file is 
converted to Excel or after it is converted to Excel so it does not matter at what point it should convert it.
I got the following code by searching in the Google but due to not being good at VB script, I am not able to combine them two files. I tried different ways but I am getting one error or another.

```
Sub macro2()
Dim i As Long, lcol As Long
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
lcol = .Range("A1"). End(xLToRight).Column
For i = lcol To 1 Step -1
If.Cells(1, i).Value = "#N/A" Then .Rows(i).Delete
Next i
End With
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Updated Code Only to delete #N/A

```
    Sub DeleteErrorRows()
    'The path to the workbook in which to search.
   'Defining the variables

    Dim MyPath, MySheet,MyWB

    MyPath = "C:\PR\TEST\Sizetest.xls"
    'The name of the workbook in which to search.
    MyWB = "SizeGuideLookup_test.xls"

    'Use the current sheet as the place to store the data for which to search.
    MySheet = ActiveSheet.Name

   'If an error occurs, use the error handling routine at the end of this file.
    'On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    'Turn off screen updating, and then open the target workbook.
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False


     Const strERROR = "#N/A"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim i, lastRow, rw
    Dim rFound
    Dim sList
    Workbooks.Open MyPath
    'Workbooks.Open FileName:=MyPath & MyWB
    set wb = Workbooks.Open(objFile.Mypath, ReadOnly:=True, CorruptLoad:=xlExtractData)
    wb.Close
    Set sList = CreateObject("System.Collections.Sortedlist")

    Set rFound = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:=strERROR, After:=Range("A1"), Lookat:=xlPart,LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)

    If rFound Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    lastRow = rFound.Row

    For i = 1 To lastRow
        Set rFound = Rows(i).Find(What :=strERROR, After:=Rows(i).Cells(1, Columns.Count), Lookat:=xlPart, _
                                            LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
            If Not sList.ContainsKey(i) Then
                sList.Add i, vbNullString
            End If
        End If
    Next

    For i = sList.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        rw = sList.GetKey(i)
        Rows(rw).Delete
    Next

    DeleteErrorRows

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'conn.close
End Sub
```

I am getting error  on the following line of code. Error says 'Expected End of Statement )' This code seems ok to me. There might be other errors and I am trying to get this program to work.                                                                                  `Set rFound = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:=strERROR, After:=Range("A1"), Lookat:=xlPart,LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Delete all Rows with a #N/A Error from an Excel Worksheet using either VBA or VBScript

```
Sub RemoveErrorRows(oWorksheet)
    Const strERROR = "#N/A"
    Const xlValues = -4163
    Const xlPart = 2
    Const xlByRows = 1
    Const xlNext = 1

    Dim rFound, lastRow, x

    With oWorksheet
        Do
            Set rFound = .Rows.Find(CStr(strERROR), .UsedRange.Cells(1, .Columns.Count), xlValues, xlPart, xlByRows, xlNext)
            If rFound Is Nothing Then
                Exit Do
            Else
                .Rows(rFound.Row).Delete
            End If

        Loop

    End With

End Sub
```